# My Blender doesnt render in image window

Tags: rendering

Blender looks like it is rendering but doesn't slowly tile an image any more. My other blender files render fine so I have obviously clicked the wrong button somewhere. (sorry the file is too big to upload in the Blender Exchange)

[image: my screen as it is supposed to be rendering]

Comment: It doesn't look like it has started rendering yet, it says "Synchronising object" in the image editor, showing it is still loading objects to be rendered.

Comment: My thoughts too. And by the looks of it, if you say the file is too big I smell a too complex object in the scene is causing a big slowdown

Comment: I took out a load of particle systems it is much faster, but it doesn't produce the background grid and start tiling it, though a render does occasionally appear in the composite node editor